# Using AJAX with a Django MultipleChoiceField with multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I'm sending the data from a form with MultipleChoiceField via AJAX and in the template I have multiple checkboxes. I am having problems sending the selected checkboxes.
My first attempt was this:

```
var selected =[];
        $('.checkboxes:checked').each(function(){
            selected.push($(this).val())
        });
```

and then in $.ajax:

```
data: {
            email : $('[name=email]').val(),
            country: $('[name=country]').val(),
            category: selected,
```

but this didn't work.
After this I tried to send in the selected values as a string and then just split them and create a list in the view. I managed to do that but I now can't figure out on how to replace the value of the field in the form.

```
form = SubscriberForm(request.POST)
        categories = form['category'].value()
        category = categories[0].split(',')
        del category[-1]
        form.instance.category = category
```

I'm not sure as to why this doesn't work. I even tried setting a dummy string just to see if the problem was with my category variable but that didn't work either.